# Why aren't my Facebook plugins working?

Tags: facebook

These things are giving me hell...

http://sas98.user.srcf.net/like/index.php

There should be a login box at the top. I find it doesn't change after a user has logged in (at least it should disappear, I gather there is no logout option).

There should be a facepile under the thumbnail when you hover your mouse over the like button, but this doesn't appear for me in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox.

Any ideas would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a javascript error in your code.  
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - index.php:21`

This is your current code :

```
FB.init({
  appId      : '310361742327759', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//www.sas98.user.srcf.net/like/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  oath       : true;
});
```

- You are missing a comma on the 6th line - after the xfbml parameter.
- In addition you have a semi-colon terminating the last line.
- Finally you have a type the **oauth** parameter wrong...

---

Edit : After further editing you seem to have fixed those errors - your problem now with the login button is slightly different.   You can test to see if the user is logged in and only if the user is **not** logged in you can display the login button.  There **is** also a logout function.  Please review the [Javascript SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for information on how to manipulate the login/logout flow for facebook authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited all of that but it's still not working as it should. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Edit: what happens is that the login button doesn't appear (regardless of whether I'm logged in or not) until I hover over the like button...

Comment: My friend, you still have javascript errors.  You should use the [chrome developers tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) if you are using chrome, or [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you are using firefox.  Please correct your syntax errors first.

Comment: ok - i see you have corrected most of your errors - you now have only one error left (that i can spot) - and that is a spelling mistake in the oauth parameter.

Comment: Sorry, my FTP keeps giving me local files instead of downloading them so I'm editing stuff with previous mistakes in. It should all be corrected now but the login button doesn't disappear and facepile is still not present.

Comment: i edited my answer with some more info.  If you start using those tools i mentioned you'll be able to deal with these issues much more easily.After loggin in to your app successfully, I am not getting a message when I click on the login button saying that you are calling the login function when i am already logged in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look through the documentation. This is much more complex than I thought it'd be, I don't understand why a logout button isn't coded into the iframe... Do you have any idea why facepile isn't working? It's quite central to my site.

Comment: I cant see any facepile plugin in your source... Perhaps you are referring to pictures of friends below the login button?  If so then you should just set `data-show-faces` parameter to `true` in the login button.  Once again - please read more in the documentation.  It isn't really that complicated.

Comment: Sorry, it's in the Javascript: http://sas98.user.srcf.net/like/jquery.hovercard.min.js

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because this: [Breaking Change: JavaScript SDK to oauth:true on December 13th](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/614/)

Comment: If you would have looked at the URL that was provided you would have clearly seen that the `oauth:true` parameter **was** set.

Comment: @Sebastian, setting that value was the right thing to do... See my answer for some other things you missed.